# spring boot component with string parameters

Tags: spring, spring-boot

i have a component that reads a configuration value from application.properties and accepts a string parameter in its constructor as such..

```
@Component
public class Person 
{
    @Value("${greeting}")
    String greeting;
    
    String name;
    
    public Person(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
        
        onGreet( greeting + ", " + name );
    }
    
    public void onGreet(String message)
    {
    }
}
```

I need to instantiate this component as follows and override its "onGreet" event in the calling code as follows:

```
Person jack = new Person("jack")
{
    public void onGreet(String message)
    {
        System.out.println( message );
    }
};
```

However I end up getting this..

Parameter 0 of constructor in demo11.Person required a bean of type 'java.lang.String' that could not be found.

My application.properties is as follows:

```
greeting=hello
```

What am I missing here? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is literally telling you that the only constructor that you have requires a parameter that Spring knows nothing about.

Add a @Value to that String name in the constructor (right before the parameter) like so `public Person(@Value("${name}") String name)` if you want Spring to initalize it or remove that constructor

EDIT: some more explanation:

Spring is a dependency injection container. Meaning you define beans and let Spring create and inject them for you. Defining beans can be done in several ways (Java configuration, annotations or xml) here you are using annotation way via `@Component`.

Now that you have defined your bean (aka component) for Spring it will create it. For it to create it it needs to call a constructor. For that you need to provide it with all information necessary for constructor call - meaning all parameters. If parameters are other classes they need to be defined as beans as well (For example via @Component) if they are simple types like String you need to provide @Value for them.

Lastly if you ever use `new ...` to define Spring managed beans then the whole Spring magic disappears since Spring doesnt know about this bean instantiation anymore and will not autowire anything into it. For all intenses and purposes Spring is not aware of any objects you create with `new`.

Comment: making the constructor as you suggested "public Person(@Value("${name}") String name)" resulted in "Could not resolve placeholder 'name' in value "${name}"".

Comment: and i need that constructor. that component , which is an example , requires one parameter defined in application.properties and one passed during instantiating it using "new". my other requirement is to implement its events like i did in example. this is an example just to illustrate my needs.

Comment: Naturally u need to specify name in application.properties for Spring to have it. I feel like you are not clear on the fact that Spring is taking over the instantiation of the components so you need to provide all the information for the instantiation (constructor parameters) beforehand

Comment: Also if you use “new” spring will NOT fill any values in the component - again you need to let Spring create your objects via @Autowired

Comment: is there any way to "inject" values in application.properties into a pojo? i'm guessing if i want to use "new" there is no way and i have to read application.properties as a regular resource file myself.

Comment: correct, without usage of Spring for instantiation you would have to write a Property reader yourself - here is an example that I have once implemented https://github.com/asgarov1/elevator-challenge/blob/master/src/main/java/com/asgarov/elevator_challenge/util/PropertiesReader.java

Comment: i have been trying to inject a bunch of values in application.properties into a pojo for days to no avail. i did as you suggested , read file myself , and was done in a minute. thank you.